# Ubuntu Desktop 17.04. on Kodi Krypton. Video is great, no audio though

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 17.04, kodi

For all you moderators: (Legal Kodi Add-ons only!)

My system Audio Output is HDMI/Displayport 2 (Built in Audio) running on an ASUS H170M-Plus CSM Motherboard with an Intel i5 Skylake cpu.

Things I've tried already:

1. Wired keyboard vs wireless
2. Checking Audio Settings to ensure both volume amp and reduction settings are at 0. (Top Right Red Volume Circle Error)
3. Changing Audio Output Device settings in Kodi from: Audio Output Device (PULSEAUDIO) to Built In Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958) Digital Output (S/PDIF) (PULSEAUDIO)

Not sure if there is something that I need to add in to get PulseAudio to work correctly with my system/Kodi? Any guidance would be appreciated!

Disclaimer: I'm ok with the Ubuntu CLI but definitely no pro.

Comment: Please confirm: Audio works everywhere but Kodi? If it works then generally Kodi works (with the default setting which is to use the default system wide audio device). If not, you have to troubleshoot the audio, not Kodi.

Comment: Hi Michael: Confirmed. Both Left and Right speakers test out OK for HDMI/DISPLAYPORT 2 Everywhere(I've tested) minus Kodi

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly select the HDMI output instead of the default in Kodi? Doesn't work either? Well, my next guess would be Kodi is muted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike, Weird answer for you, and anyone else reading this.

I installed pavucontrol. For some reason the correct output being recognized after that program was installed solved the problem. Previously the HDMI output was not being recognized inside Kodi.